# refrence class not found in cakehphp environment in phpstorm

Tags: php, cakephp, phpstorm

I had installed phpstorm editor first time to work in cake php editor in my local system (wamp)
After doing lots of research i had done basic configuration and installed phpunit.phar also selected it in an option in Editor but still its showing class not found error if i try to run it.

Though its working fine if I run it directly in my browser by typing url (local host)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You are executing PHPUnit tests in CLI environment ..  Is that is what you want to do? Because running your project in browser is a different thing. If you intended to run PHPUnit tests .. then make sure that it can load all your classes (e.g. `bootstrap.php` that is used by PHPUnit or whatever).

Comment: @LazyOne  tnx for your help  but actually m new to cake php and new to php storm 
i read that i can debug and run php like visual studio in phpstorm (as run as showing that ) 

i dint want to run phpunit test but i read some steps on google and just followed them

can you plz suggest any other option so that i can just run and debug cake php here tnx in advance

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/ (get trough all steps from start to end), but the "Run and Debug Your Application" section in particular. Other tutorials/articles/how-to's can be found here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials